# how to tune number of threads started by workers in AKKA?

Tags: multithreading, scala, akka

I created an application that uses Akka with RoundRobin routers. The application takes a list of files and the processes them in parallel. My issue is that regardless of the number of workers that I specify the application processes only 12 files at a time. Is there a certain setting that I need to change ?

```
   val workers = context.actorOf(Props[ItemProcessingWorker].withRouter(RoundRobinRouter(nworkers)))
```

update: I tried to send the params via config programmatically.. still not working.

```
    val conf1 = ConfigFactory.load(ConfigFactory.parseString("""
 akka {
  default-dispatcher {
    # Dispatcher is the name of the event-based dispatcher
    type = Dispatcher
    # What kind of ExecutionService to use
    executor = "fork-join-executor"
    # Configuration for the fork join pool
    fork-join-executor {
      # Min number of threads to cap factor-based parallelism number to
      parallelism-min = 32
      # Parallelism (threads) ... ceil(available processors * factor)
      parallelism-factor = 1.0
      # Max number of threads to cap factor-based parallelism number to
      parallelism-max = 32
    }
    # Throughput defines the maximum number of messages to be
    # processed per actor before the thread jumps to the next actor.
    # Set to 1 for as fair as possible.
    throughput = 1000
  }}

 """))
 val system = ActorSystem("MySystem2",conf1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I got this resolved, I was missing a sub configuration 
instead of

```
akka {
  default-dispatcher {
    type = Dispatcher
    executor = "thread-pool-executor"
    throughput = 1000    
    fork-join-executor {
      parallelism-min = 32
      parallelism-factor = 0.5
      parallelism-max = 64
    }
  }
}
```

it should be

```
akka {
  actor{
    default-dispatcher {
      type = Dispatcher
      executor = "thread-pool-executor"
      throughput = 1000    
      fork-join-executor {
        parallelism-min = 32
        parallelism-factor = 0.5
        parallelism-max = 64
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `resources/application.conf` try changing the values of the `default-dispatcher`

```
akka {
      default-dispatcher {
        # Dispatcher is the name of the event-based dispatcher
        type = Dispatcher
        # What kind of ExecutionService to use
        executor = "fork-join-executor"
        # Configuration for the fork join pool
        fork-join-executor {
          # Min number of threads to cap factor-based parallelism number to
          parallelism-min = 16
          # Parallelism (threads) ... ceil(available processors * factor)
          parallelism-factor = 2.0
          # Max number of threads to cap factor-based parallelism number to
          parallelism-max = 32
        }
        # Throughput defines the maximum number of messages to be
        # processed per actor before the thread jumps to the next actor.
        # Set to 1 for as fair as possible.
        throughput = 20
      }
}
```

Comment: I am running this from eclipse. can I put the configuration code in reference.conf?

Comment: You should be. Is that where you put all your configuration values right now ?

Comment: yes, it has no impact at all. there are still only 12 running threads at a time !

Comment: try putting application.conf there and also tweak your parallelism factor ? How many cores does your machine have ?

Comment: I have 4 cores on my machine. For some reason the configuration are not being picked up by the application, so even when I lowered the values  parallelism-max = 32 to 5 , the application is still processing 12 files !!

Comment: You need to change the parallelism factor to something more than 3. The default value is 3, and you have 4 core. So you get 12. (see - https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L290). Once you change that in the correct place you should be able to go beyond 12.

Comment: It should be akka.actor.default-dispatcher rather than akka.default-dispatcher.