# New I/O worker threads in akka applications

Tags: akka

In VisualVM I observe a lot of threads that have the similar names:

`New I/O worker # <somenumber>`

I'm wondering where can I control the number of that threads and what does they stand for?

**EDIT**
The question isn't about how to tune default dispatcher's thread-pool. That threads have differnet name

[image: example]

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to tune number of threads started by workers in AKKA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27118816/how-to-tune-number-of-threads-started-by-workers-in-akka)

Comment: no, it's not duplicate. That topic shows how to tune default-dispatcher's thread pool. `New I/O worker` threads don't relate to it.

Comment: I believe those are the threads created by netty for akka-cluster and akka-remote. Look for some configs in those libraries.

Comment: I believe these are Netty threads. I have the same problem but I'm pretty sure it’s my fault. I say that because I use Dispatch which uses the Async HTTP client library which has switchable providers. When I switch to Grizzly the same thing happens but with a different pool of threads.

Comment: June 2016, seeing this issue using dispatch as well!

Comment: @user2827214 if you switch to dispatch 0.11.3 you will be able to specify a SocketChannelFactory to a NettyAsyncHttpProviderConfig to the AsyncHttpClientConfig